# add some data to sql server every month

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want automatic insertion of the data into table every month.

For example there is a table `Cost`. If there wasn't new data this month(before for example some day of the month) then script should insert data from previous month. I mean

```
 1234 1.10.1992
 1334 1.11.1992
 *no data 1.12 was added*
 1334 1.12.1992
```

I decided to use sql server jobs. I've created a job

```
exec sp_add_job
     @job_name = 'Add land cost automatic'
```

then I've created a schedule and attached it to the job

```
use msdb;
go

exec sp_add_schedule
    @schedule_name = 'Add',
    @freq_type = 16,
    @freq_interval = 2,
    @freq_recurrence_factor = 1;
go

exec sp_attach_schedule
    @job_name = 'Add land cost automatic',
    @schedule_name = 'Add';
go
```

But how to add job step and what to write as a command?

Comment: To create job step I suppose you did already take a look  [sp_add_jobstep](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187358.aspx)? But I don't see clearly what's your main concern. Could you please detail a bit more what do you expect the statements to do?

Comment: You appear to be scheduling the job to run on the 2nd day of each month.  Do you want to add the last known cost for the prior month as the cost on the 1st day of the new month or the last day of the prior month?  Or something else entirely?

Comment: The idea is if the user didn't insert new value before 2.XX - it insert it automatically. To make the story simple - it just has updates every month

Comment: Are you wanting to programmatically add a job step here? Why not simply create a sproc that grabs the necessary data and add its execution as a job step manually?